# Working Gesture with Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I want to achieve the following task with gesture events in Windows Phone:

I have a single XAML page with an int-label in the middle with the value set as "1". If a user swipes their finger from right to left, the value should change to "-1". If a user swipes their finger from left to right, the value should change to "+1".

Can anyone guide me in achieving the above mentioned task?

Thanks!